# Any way to read from STDIN synchronously without extra modules/libraries (Node.JS)?

Tags: node.js

Is there any way I read from STDIN **synchronously** without the need to install any extra modules? Preferably using the FS built-in module.

Comment: Yes. Look at the built in [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) core module.

Comment: Provide an example..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually need to read **synchronously** you can use `fs.readSync` on a `stdin` (`/dev/stdin` on Unix systems) file descriptor:

Example:

```js
const fs = require("fs")    
    
const stdinReadSync = (size = 1024, encoding = 'utf-8') => {     
    const buff = Buffer.alloc(size);        
    fs.readSync(0, buff, 0, size);          
    return buff.toString(encoding);        
}                                            
     
const result = stdinReadSync();    
console.log(result);
```

But I would suggest writing some `Promise` wrapper around `process.stdin`